# Avoid my application to read the Return as a character

Tags: c

I have this loop in my console application :

```
do{
    printf("\n %sVotre choix :%s ",GREEN_BOLD,RESETCOLOR);
    choix = tolower(getchar());
}while((choix != 'c') && (choix != 'l') && (choix != 'e') && (choix != 's'));
```

So when the user types a character which is not one of `c`, `l`, `e`, or `s`, he will get the message `Votre choix :`  again and the program waits him to enter some other character, but the problem is that the user gets that message twice, and I think it's because when the user types some character and then he strikes `Return`, in the next iteration that `Return` it will be read as a character, and this is a screenshot of what I'm getting:

[image: another screenshot]

How can I stop my application from reading the `Return` as a character?

Answer (score 0):

Use `" %c"` to first consume previous whitespace, including a "Return", then read 1 `char`.

```
char choix = 0;
do {
  printf("\n %sVotre choix :%s ",GREEN_BOLD,RESETCOLOR);
  // choix = tolower(getchar());
  scanf(" %c", &choix);
  choix = tolower(choix);
} while((choix != 'c') && (choix != 'l') && (choix != 'e') && (choix != 's'));
```

A better approach, use the `fgets() sscanf()` team.

```
char choix;
do {
  printf("\n %sVotre choix :%s ",GREEN_BOLD,RESETCOLOR);
  char buf[10];
  if (fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) == NULL) break; // EOF or I/O error
  if (sscanf(buf, " %c", &choix) != 1) continue;
  choix = tolower(choix);
} while((choix != 'c') && (choix != 'l') && (choix != 'e') && (choix != 's'));
```